# Having Z-Fighting Issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, webgl, babylonjs

I am using Babylon.js to make a 3D game. My project is meant to be run on all browsers. However, when users run it in Firefox it seems as though there is a bit of Z-Fighting issues where some 3d objects will not render correctly or not at all! I also noticed that some textures would have striped seams running diagonally like so...

[image]

I did some research online and I found out about the *z-index* property for **.css**. I played around with this setting but it did not solve the issue for me. I am open to any suggestion(s) to help me fix this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: We need some code to go on really, if possible use the [babylon playground](http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/) and link us to it. To take a wild guess, the sharp edges is to do with anti-aliasing, and 3D is relatively new. Try changing any perspective values.

Comment: @jaunt YESS! I found the .js class that handles everything that has to do with the camera setting. I played a bit with some of the values and it seems that it is starting to fix some of that z-fighting issue. I'll get it fixed in no time now. Thank you!

Comment: [this answer might help you understand z-fighting issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21106656/128511)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as my comment proved useful, I'll just re-quote it here to allow this answer to be marked as accepted.

> To take a wild guess, the sharp edges is to do with anti-aliasing, and 3D is relatively new. Try changing any perspective values.

Answer (score 1):

This may also be a firefox bug related [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1202387) 2 days ago. When you set `antialias:false`, firefox also needs `stencil:true` to enable the 24-bit depth buffer.

Answer (score 0):

## z-fighting (in 2020)

BABYLON.js evolved since 2015, so here are my suggestions on what to try to fight the z-fighting:

1. `material.useLogarithmicDepth = true;`
   for all meterials in your scene. See this [how to](https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/using_logarithmic_depth_buffer).
2. Adjust `material.zOffset` (negative values enforce depth-shift towards camera). See this [playground](https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#1NYKLE#3).

Note that `z-index` and *css* as asked in the question in general have no effect on the 3D scene. It lives in its own world inside of the `<canvas>` element. 3D objects are not DOM elements, each engine (BABYLON, THREE, etc.) represents them in it's own way.