# I render a house mode,and at first I find some wall will be flickering

Tags: three.js

I render a house mode,and at first I find some wall will be flickering ，

[image]

so  i  try to add the renderer :

```
   new WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true,
        logarithmicDepthBuffer:true
    });
```

But another problem has emerged，the camera will clip  the wall.like this

[image]

this is my camera near-far config:

```
this.camera.near = 0.001;
this.camera.far = 1000;
```

Comment: The flickering is known as Z-Fighting, it occurs when two parallel planes are very close or exactly over each other. The renderer then has problems to decide which of the two plane should be rendered. There are already some posts about Z-Fighting that may help you further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328722/how-can-i-solve-z-fighting-using-three-js

Comment: To your second problem it could be that your model is just too small for your camera. You could try to scale up all models.

Comment: But if i set the `logarithmicDepthBuffer:false`，it will not become this way.So is there any way to make it  work，not 'flickering ' and 'clipped'